# Add computed column

Tags: sql-server

---

This is my table:
with these columns:

```
ShiftId ShiftNum    Date    ShiftType   StartTime   EndTime
1   1   2014-08-07  A   0:00:00 6:00:00
2   2   2014-08-07  B   6:01:00 18:00:00
3   3   2014-08-07  A   18:00:01    23:59:00
4   1   2014-08-08  A   0:00:00 6:00:00
5   2   2014-08-08  C   6:01:00 18:00:00
6   3   2014-08-08  B   18:00:01    23:59:00
7   1   2014-08-09  B   0:00:00 6:00:00
8   2   2014-08-09  C   6:01:00 18:00:00
9   3   2014-08-09  B   18:00:01    23:59:00
10  1   2014-08-10  B   0:00:00 6:00:00
11  2   2014-08-10  D   6:01:00 18:00:00
12  3   2014-08-10  C   18:00:01    23:59:00
13  1   2014-08-11  C   0:00:00 6:00:00
14  2   2014-08-11  D   6:01:00 18:00:00
15  3   2014-08-11  C   18:00:01    23:59:00
16  1   2014-08-12  C   0:00:00 6:00:00
17  2   2014-08-12  A   6:01:00 18:00:00
18  3   2014-08-12  D   18:00:01    23:59:00
19  1   2014-08-13  D   0:00:00 6:00:00
20  2   2014-08-13  A   6:01:00 18:00:00
21  3   2014-08-13  D   18:00:01    23:59:00
22  1   2014-08-14  D   0:00:00 6:00:00
23  2   2014-08-14  B   6:01:00 18:00:00
```

I want to add "DailyShiftId" column as computrd column means when  shiftType changed then DailyShiftId has been increased.

```
ShiftId ShiftNum    Date    ShiftType   StartTime   EndTime DailyShiftId
1   1   2014-08-07  A   0:00:00 6:00:00 1
2   2   2014-08-07  B   6:01:00 18:00:00    2
3   3   2014-08-07  A   18:00:01    23:59:00    3
4   1   2014-08-08  A   0:00:00 6:00:00 3
5   2   2014-08-08  C   6:01:00 18:00:00    4
6   3   2014-08-08  B   18:00:01    23:59:00    5
7   1   2014-08-09  B   0:00:00 6:00:00 5
8   2   2014-08-09  C   6:01:00 18:00:00    6
9   3   2014-08-09  B   18:00:01    23:59:00    7
10  1   2014-08-10  B   0:00:00 6:00:00 7
11  2   2014-08-10  D   6:01:00 18:00:00    8
12  3   2014-08-10  C   18:00:01    23:59:00    9
13  1   2014-08-11  C   0:00:00 6:00:00 9
14  2   2014-08-11  D   6:01:00 18:00:00    10
15  3   2014-08-11  C   18:00:01    23:59:00    11
16  1   2014-08-12  C   0:00:00 6:00:00 11
17  2   2014-08-12  A   6:01:00 18:00:00    12
18  3   2014-08-12  D   18:00:01    23:59:00    13
19  1   2014-08-13  D   0:00:00 6:00:00 13
20  2   2014-08-13  A   6:01:00 18:00:00    14
21  3   2014-08-13  D   18:00:01    23:59:00    15
22  1   2014-08-14  D   0:00:00 6:00:00 15
23  2   2014-08-14  B   6:01:00 18:00:00    16
```

how can I do it?

Comment: `shiftType changed `?? while updating??

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: **"strong text"**... Your text (spelling, casing etc) isn't that strong!

Comment: or do you want to add that "column" as column in your query?

Comment: If you are using computed column in its technical [SQL Server sense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) then it cannot be done - computed columns can (outside of ugly hacks) only reference other columns in the same row. If you just mean "add a new column to a query" then it may be best to edit your question and clarify your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `DailyShiftId` as a normal column and add an `AFTER UPDATE Trigger` on your table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TAU_MyTable
ON MyTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE MyTable SET DailyShiftId = DailyShiftId + 1 
    WHERE [INSERTED].ShiftType <> [DELETED].ShiftType

END
```

OR

You can add a function to the database to calculate value of the new column and use Computed Column Specification as done here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/formula-for-computed-column-specification-property-in-sql-se/

Comment: Wont that `UPDATE` every single row in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Create On Update Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER ViewEmployeeTrigger ON Employee
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE Employee 
SET DailyShiftId=DailyShiftId+1
-- what ever your updation logic
FROM INSERTED I JOIN Employee C ON I.ShiftId= C.ShiftId


END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This Query will be helpful to you to get the **expected result without using trigger**.

```
  DECLARE @Test Table
(
    ShiftId Integer,
    ShiftNum Int,
    Date DATETIME,
    ShiftType VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @Test (ShiftId, ShiftNum, Date, ShiftType)

SELECT 1,   1,   '2014-08-07',  'A'    UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   2,   '2014-08-07',  'B'    UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   3,   '2014-08-07',  'A'    UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   1,   '2014-08-08',  'A'    UNION ALL
SELECT 5,   2,   '2014-08-08',  'C'    UNION ALL
SELECT 6,   3,   '2014-08-08',  'B'    UNION ALL
SELECT 7,   1,   '2014-08-09',  'B'         

   SELECT C.ShiftId, C.ShiftNum, C.Date, C.ShiftType , 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER( order by C.DailyShift ASC) AS DailyShift
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT A.*,
            CASE WHEN A.ShiftType = B.ShiftType  
                Then ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.ShiftId ASC) - 1 
                Else  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.ShiftId ASC)
            END AS DailyShift
        FROM @Test AS A LEFT JOIN @Test AS B ON A.ShiftId = B.ShiftId + 1  
    ) AS C
```

**Using Computed Column:**

Add the column to the table specifing the function (**Calculate**).

```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
    ADD DailyShiftID AS dbo.Calculate(ShiftId, ShiftType)

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Calculate(@nShiftId INT, @sShiftType VARCHAR(1))
RETURNS INT
AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @sPrevShiftType AS VARCHAR(1)
    DECLARE @nDailyShift AS INT

    SELECT @sPrevShiftType =  ShiftType, @nDailyShift =  ISNULL(DailyShiftID, 0) 
    FROM TableName WHERE ShiftId = @nShiftId - 1

    IF (@sPrevShiftType <> @sShiftType)
        SET @nDailyShift = @nDailyShift + 1

      RETURN @nDailyShift        
  END
```

Comment: Have you got the result? if yes, then mark it as answer.

Comment: thank you for answer. but i want to add this column to my table as computed column. can you help me?

Comment: hi Kumar,how do I use this query as computed column?

Comment: I have updated the answer to get the result using computed column. Verify it.